# How do i run a js function from an iframe in the main frame?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, iframe

In my iframe i have a function:

```
function CheckDebug(){
        if($('#debug').length > 0){
            debugConsole.debugOn = true;
            debugConsole.IP = "<?=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']?>";
            debugConsole.log('START DEBUG MODE');
        }
    }
```

How do i run that function in the main frame so that it affects the iframe's `debugConsole` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the parent iframe use [window.parent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.parent), you can call:

```
window.parent
```

So you would do:

```
window.parent.debugConsole(..);
```

as an example.

To have the parent access the iframe, you can do the following:

```
document.getElementById('frameId').contentWindow.funcThatLivesInIframe();
```

where the iframe has an id attribute with the value 'frameId'.

Comment: Your second part worked! thanks so much! i cant accept for another 9 minutes lol

Answer (score 0):

Just access the "top" context:

```
function CheckDebug(){
    if (top.$('#debug').length > 0){
        top.debugConsole.debugOn = true;
        top.debugConsole.IP = "<?=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']?>";
        top.debugConsole.log('START DEBUG MODE');
    }
}
```

Now that's for the top-most window.  If you just want to go up one level, you can look at "window.parent."

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "manipulate the iframe".  What exactly do you want to do to it?  The parent/child relationship can be done in a lot of ways, and you haven't posted that much code to make clear what it is that your pages do.